# Can IIS be configure to forward request to another web server?

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I have several web site set up on one IIS 6 server distinguished by Host Header.

However, I wish to have one of the sites served by a Linux / Apache server on my network. Do I need to use a reverse proxy add-in for IIS, or is there a simple way to tell IIS to pass on all requests to another server?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

For IIS 7.5, Microsoft provides official modules for this!

- URL Rewrite: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite
- Reverse proxy: http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

In the site settings, you'll get an "URL Rewrite" icon.

- Open it
- right click on the "inbound rules list"
- Select "Add Rule(s)"
- Choose "Reverse proxy"

In this dialog you can enter the hostname + port to forward to. After adding the rule, opening the edit dialog offers more customizations.

Comment: That's nice and all, but the original question specified IIS 6, so I'm confused that an answer specific to IIS 7.5 has been marked as 'accepted'. Was there a solution for IIS 6?

Comment: @Tim: you can use the ISAPI rewrite mentioned below, but other then that, I'm not familiar with IIS6 solutions.

Comment: I'm having troubles on my Win10 machine and I can't install this. Are there any limitations for these modules? Is it necessary to run it on a Server OS from MS? thanks

Comment: Be advised that there are problems reverse proxying POST requests using this method

Comment: @fpdragon ARR 3.0 URL Rewrite 2.1 installed via the web platform installer worked for me on Win10/IIS10 without issue.

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen Could you please point us to some more details about the potential POST issues?

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen Could you elaborate on potential problems reverse proxying POST requests?

Answer (score 17):

I'm using a third-party software for Windows (IIS) for this purpose, which - besides other things like URL rewriting - does this job pretty well: [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

> ISAPI Rewrite is a powerful URL
>   manipulation engine based on regular
>   expressions. It acts mostly like
>   Apache's mod_Rewrite, but is designed
>   specifically for Microsoft's Internet
>   Information Server (IIS).
>   ISAPI Rewrite is an ISAPI filter
>   written in pure C/C++ so it is
>   extremely fast. ISAPI_Rewrite gives
>   you the freedom to go beyond the
>   standard URL schemes and develop your
>   own scheme.

Search for "Proxying". Here is the [documentation for the RewriteProxy Rule](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#RewriteProxy).

There is also a very similar open-source project: [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF).

Comment: link to doc for IIRF ProxyPass: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf20Help/html/d9d3d4d7-7b3a-4418-b290-c297b041ff42.htm

Comment: +1 - This works well on IIS 6.

Comment: I was unable to use IIRF on Windows 2008 R2 SP1, because of this issue: http://iirf.codeplex.com/workitem/32479

Answer (score 1):

No, not on IIS 6.  Look at using nginx/ubuntu (or even nginx on windows) as a reverse proxy in front of your IIS6 server.  We had to use IIS7.5 for reverse proxy features

Answer (score -2):

This [Microsoft KB article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true) should help answer this request.

Procedures to redirect requests to another Web site or directory:

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or directory you want to redirect, and click Properties.
2. Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.
3. Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection to a URL.
4. In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the destination directory or Web site.

Comment: Given the "reverse-proxy" tag on the poster's question I'm guessing he's looking for reverse proxy functionality and not an HTTP redirect.

Comment: The other server is not publicly available so unfortunately this wouldn't work

Comment: This is just plain wrong.