# Windows Server 2003 with Apache and IIS causing random faulting and performance issues with Apache?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, apache-2.2, iis-6

I'm trying to fix a problem on a Windows Server 2003 SE install which is running IIS6 and Apache webserver (with PHP and MySQL). IIS sites are bound to one IP, Apache to the other. Everything seemed fine till the other IP address was installed to allow a webservice to run under IIS.

Symptoms:

- Apache now responds very slowly, even requests for static files (often 30 seconds or more)
- Sporadic errors are appearing in the event logs like: `Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.14.0, faulting module php5ts.dll, version 5.2.13.13, fault address 0x000ac14f.`

I've double-checked the config files, taken account of this question/answer [Running IIS and Apache on the same Windows Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/51230/running-iis-and-apache-on-the-same-windows-server), upped the Apache log level to debug, run TCPView to check for conflicting bindings, upgraded to latest Apache/PHP versions but still no success or indication of a cause.

Any suggestions on where to look, or debugging tips would be gratefully received. I'm a web programmer so not so familiar with Windows Server admin or details of the networking stack. Running PHP under IIS is not an option and hosting on another server is non-ideal.

Comment: Is your PHP installation shared by both IIS and Apache?  They may be trying to load the same module which could lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Justin, didn't think of that. I've checked under IIS Manager > Web Service Extensions but I don't see PHP enabled there.