# Another website in a IIS subfolder

Tags: iis, web-server, wordpress, lamp, seo

A friend of mine has an ASP.NET site hosted on windows server with IIS7 web server. He wants to install a wordpress blog without using subdomains for SEO reasons. In practice, he would like to have a blog calling url like "site.com/subfolder". I would like to avoid installing PHP on his production server ... I'd rather put WP under LAMP. Is it possible to achieve the same result "hijacking" the subfolder on another server?

Comment: Set up a [reverse proxy][1] to forward requests to the Apache server.


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a reverse proxy for this. Here is a blog post that helped me when I did something similar:

[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)

I haven't tested it with Wordpress, though, and writing URL rewrite rules for a web application can be tricky: you will need to test and adapt to Wordpress. Fortunately, unless you installed very complex addons, Wordpress is pretty friendly to reverse proxies so hopefully it will work without too much trouble.