# Fowarding web applications according to domain name from IIS to Glassfish or Apache

Tags: reverse-proxy, reverse-dns, iis-10

I have installed three HTTP servers (**IIS**, **Glassfish4** and **Apache2.2**) on a single windows-OS-based **VPS**.

And I have three domain names (*www.mysampleglass-domain.com* *www.mysampleapach-domain.org* and *www.mysampleiis-domain.net*) which point to my VPS IP (as **DNS** A zone)

Actually, IIS is the main server and is responsible for listening to http request on port 80. At present, all three domain names are pointing to the default Website from **IIS** where I use the **URL_Rewrite**(+Reverse Proxy).

Can anyone tell me Which kind of rules do I need to add to accomplish these following goals:

- if user hit www.mysampleapach-domain.com in browser, he must be served content at 127.0.0.1:8080 (PHP based application)
- if user hit www.mysampleglass-domain.com in browser, he must be served content at 127.0.0.1:18080 (JSP based application)
- if user hit www.mysampleiis-domain.net he must be served the content from 127.0.0.1:8018 (.net based application)

Or is there another solution (no third party software to install please) In addition, users should not see the port in their browser.

In Apache, it is possible to do this using VirtualHost but I don't know how to do it in IIS. even using ARR as suggested on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server).

Comment: if Application Request Routing or plain virtual hosts doesn't help - then what you are trying to do must be enormously challenging. The answer you linked to would have been my suggestion also

Comment: How to do it using the Application Request Routing? I do have the extension installed

Comment: That's exactly the scenario for ARR, so when you said "I don't know how to", have you done any experiments? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/