How to point the domain name to (IIS Webserver) docker container?
I have set up an (IIS Webserver) Docker container on my Windows Server, running on port 8080, and successfully hosted a website inside the container. However, I am currently facing challenges in mapping a domain name to the website within the Docker container. I am unsure of the steps required to assign a domain name to the container and have been struggling with this issue for a few days. Could you please assist me in resolving this?

https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server - reverse proxy is the traditional method for this.
